# How to find on which PHP version my CakePHP website was working?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have custom made website built on CakePHP 1.3 framework. I can't update the framework, because i have so many custom made functions.

The problem is that my website doesn't work with latest PHP versions. Few weeks ago i found that many of the functions on the site doesn't work. I asked the host provider if they made any changes and they told that the server php version has been upgraded. They can't tell me what was the php verison of my acount and now i'm stuck.

Is there anyway to find out what was the php version that worked on my CakePHP script?

Comment: "They can't tell me what was the php verison of my acount" i find that hard to believe, they sound incompetent.

Comment: yes, it is, they told me that all accounts were upgraded so they have no idea what was the php version of my account. Is there a way to search CakePHP logs and to find what was the working PHP version?

Comment: most hosts would have the php version in there 'help' section, you may be able to find a cached copy? Who is the host? i'll poke about if i can

Comment: Is changing the provider an option?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a file with following code and check your php version and other informations as well

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need programatically check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

`phpversion()`

Answer (score -1):

Change your provider and [get a VPS](https://www.vpscheap.net/), you can install any php version on this virtual server instance you want then. [Read this.](https://zencache.com/new-minimum-php-version-php-5-4/)

php 5.4 has already reached it's end of life and 5.5 will do so in November 2016 as well. The best is to upgrade the server and php script to work with php 7.

Not upgrading is IMHO not an option because of security.

I'm pretty sure your site was running on 5.3 or 5.4.